# Bootstrap/CSS: Clearfix affects even/odd index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using clearfix to prevent the Bootstrap grid from breaking when I use columns of different heights.

However, once the clearfix div is added to the document, the columns that appear after it in the source behave as if they have a different even/odd index than they actually do.

I have created a relevant [demo](http://www.bootply.com/CzpCxnTyhW#http://). As you can see, removing the clearfix div, makes the colors of the divs change as if their index has changed.

Do you know what may be causing and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: because you have used *`:nth-of-type`* and which works on siblings, your *`clearfix`* breaks that sibling behavior and it doesn't matter its hidden using *CSS* or not it is there in your **DOM**

Comment: To resolve this you could make your `.clearfix` element a span

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay If it is `nth-child` what you said is correct. Since `nth-of-type` is referring to `.col-sm-6` only, adding `clearfix` shouldn't break the selection right?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Just as Safal Pillai said, wouldn't that be a matter if I had used :nth-child instead? Is there something we are missing here?

Comment: @Corporalis This indeed helps, thank you. However, I think it would be useful if someone could explain why this is happening, for me and anyone else who wants to understand this behaviour.

Comment: @ctl, I completely agree, I might have a dig around later see if I can come up with a reasonable answer, unless someone else gets there first

Comment: @Corporalis Ok, that must have sounded a bit demanding to you. I just thought you already knew the reason why this is happening. Anyway, once again, thank you.

Comment: My apologies that I didn't understand well before putting a comment, @Corporalis thanks a lot for that little trick, I'll dig some holes too to fully understand why that happened

Comment: I haven't managed to find an answer yet but interestingly `nth-child` produces the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `nth-of-type` [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo)  it specifies

> The :nth-last-of-type(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same expanded element name **after** it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent element. See :nth-child() pseudo-class for the syntax of its argument.

The key thing here is that it states:

> the same expanded element **name**

So taking that quite literally, the css selector targets a specific element and then the odd and even are matched on the specific element **name** and not the elements matched using the specific selector.

This is why replacing a `div`with a `span` will work as it will never get matched as it is a different element.

Comment: That was very helpful, I'll definitely keep it in mind. Thank you very much.